Problem updating current dropdown value from a dropdown menu created dynamically
I'm having an issue reading the value of a dynamically-created dropdown in javascript. I call the function addElement_Tract(), which is the function that creates the dropdown, and read the current value:
  $(document).ready(function() {
    addElement_Tract();
    document.getElementById('mySelect_tract').onchange = function(){
      dropdown_val_tract = document.getElementById('mySelect_tract').value;
      console.log("dropdown_val_tract is", dropdown_val_tract);
    }
   
});

Here's where I'm dynamically creating the dropdown (mySelect_tract) in the DOM:
function insertAfter_Tract(newNode, existingNode) {
    existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
}

 function addElement_Tract() {
    
    
    // create a sidebar_tract to hold legend and dropdown
    const sidebar_tract = document.createElement("div");
    sidebar_tract.className = "sidebar_tract";
    sidebar_tract.id = "sidebar_tract";
    
    //Create array of options to be added
    var display_array_tract = ["2023", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018"];
    var val_array_tract = [2023, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018];
  
    //Create and append select list
    var selectList_tract = document.createElement("select");
    selectList_tract.id = "mySelect_tract";
    selectList_tract.className = "mySelect_tract";
  
  
    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < display_array_tract.length; i++) {
        var option_tract = document.createElement("option");
        option_tract.value = Number(val_array_tract[i]);
        console.log(option_tract.value);
        option_tract.text = display_array_tract[i];
        selectList_tract.appendChild(option_tract);
    }
  
   
    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
    // Get a reference to the parent node
    const parentDiv_tract = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state_tract").parentNode;

    const mapDiv_tract = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state_tract");


    insertAfter_Tract(sidebar_tract, mapDiv_tract)

    sidebar_tract.appendChild(selectList_tract);
    
  }

Couple different problems I'm having:

the dropdown value reads as 2023, no matter what is selected (i.e. the current value selected is not being recognized).

the dropdown redraws itself on the DOM (i.e. it renders a duplicate) every time I resize the webpage. This is obviously not what I want.


I'm purposely calling the document.getElementById('mySelect_tract').onchange function after the  addElement_Tract() function, so I'm confused as to what's going on here.

the addElement_tract function adds a select list to a sidebar_tract div, but i don't see where sidebar_tract is added to the DOM.  the onchange function will have to be defined after sidebar_tract is added to the DOM, and likely whereever it is currently being added to the DOM may be the culprit of why its showing multiple times

Does this answer your question? Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript

@jet_24 see updated question - I added the function I'm using to add the dropdown to the DOM - function insertAfter_Tract

I think this is more of an issue with the r2d3 library in R, I've re-posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78492324/document-body-onload-issue-when-working-with-multiple-javascript-scripts-in-r2d3

I think we need more information, because if I just drop your JavaScript into a basic html doc (only adding a reference to jQuery and an element with the id "map_choropleth_state_tract"), it works as expected without the issue you're having.

When I run it, I get 2 dropdowns, with only the first being logged (since there's getElementById, it gets the first element with the ID, so it's only the first one that gets logged). I either don't understand your problem correctly, or it's not present for everyone.

Hi @Cybertine - please see this question here, I expanded on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78492324/document-body-onload-issue-when-working-with-multiple-javascript-scripts-in-r2d3

I can't reproduce the issue in a simple html page with only the script block and the "map_choropleth_state_tract" div element. So I think it could be that on your side the script runs several times (maybe not just on resize) which could cause the issue. Can you add a console.log() in the $(document).ready() handler to see how many times it executes and when ? The script might be included more than once, or it could be that you are also manipulating the element containing the script tag within the DOM, which would cause the browser to re-execute the script.

From what I can gather, it doesn't look like you are removing your old select box before adding the new one. I don't see where the resize event is applied so I am not sure how that function is working but I am assuming that it simply calls the addElement_Tract function.
While there are multiple ways to add event listeners to an element, typically any time you add a new element to the DOM you will also need to add any event listeners you want to it. The reason you are not able to read the value of the dropdown is because you have multiple select boxes with the same ID. The browser doesn't know which element to choose so it chooses the first one that was originally selected when the page first loaded. Also, since you only applied the change event once it is applied to the original element not to elements that are dynamically added (even though it is one with the same ID). So I suggest adjusting your code like this:
$(document).ready(initElement_Tract);

function initElement_Tract(){
    addElement_Tract();
    document.getElementById('mySelect_tract').addEventListener('change', function(){
        dropdown_val_tract = this.value;
        console.log("dropdown_val_tract is", dropdown_val_tract);
    })
}

After doing this you should also make sure to remove the previous dropdown. You can do this by creating a new function to remove it or just by doing it in the initElement_Tract function like so:
function initElement_Tract(){
    // Remove Previous dropdown
    document.getElementById('sidebar_tract')?.remove();
    
    // Add new dropdown
    addElement_Tract();

    // Add events for dropdown
    document.getElementById('mySelect_tract').addEventListener('change', function(){
        dropdown_val_tract = this.value;
        console.log("dropdown_val_tract is", dropdown_val_tract);
    })
}

Lastly if you are using a resize event I suggest including a debounce function so you can save on client resources and improve performance.
