document.body.onload issue when working with multiple javascript scripts in r2d3 (RMarkdown)
I have a two separate r2d3 chunks in an RMarkdown document, which I'm rendering to HTML.
Given the way r2d3 works, you can only have 1 script and 1 datasource that goes with each r2d3 call. (i.e. each script is completely independent of each other and works with a separate data source, etc).
This chunk produces a map, with a dropdown menu:
{r out.width='100%', fig.height=6, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    
    
    library(r2d3)
       
       r2d3(data = dataset_1,
         # this is the script for the first map.
         script = "X:/dataset_1_script.js",
         d3_version = "4",
         options(r2d3.shadow = FALSE),
         container="div",
         elementId = "map_1")


This chunk produces another map with a dropdown menu (note the script and datasource is different):
{r out.width='100%', fig.height=6, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    
    
    library(r2d3)
         
       r2d3(data = dataset_2,
         # this is the script for the second map.
         script = "X:/dataset_2_script.js",
         d3_version = "4",
         options(r2d3.shadow = FALSE),
         container="div",
         elementId = "map_2")
    
    

Here is some of the basic content in dataset_1_script.js.  The script dynamically creates a dropdown element in the DOM:
document.body.onload = addElement_Tract;

function insertAfter_Tract(newNode, existingNode) {
    existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
}

 function addElement_Tract() {
    
    
    // create a sidebar_tract to hold legend and dropdown
    const sidebar_tract = document.createElement("div");
    sidebar_tract.className = "sidebar_tract";
    sidebar_tract.id = "sidebar_tract";
    
    //Create array of options to be added
    var display_array_tract = ["2023", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018"];
    var val_array_tract = [2023, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018];
  
    //Create and append select list
    var selectList_tract = document.createElement("select");
    selectList_tract.id = "mySelect_tract";
    selectList_tract.className = "mySelect_tract";
  
  
    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < display_array_tract.length; i++) {
        var option_tract = document.createElement("option");
        option_tract.value = Number(val_array_tract[i]);
        console.log(option_tract.value);
        option_tract.text = display_array_tract[i];
        selectList_tract.appendChild(option_tract);
    }
  
   
    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
    // Get a reference to the parent node
    const parentDiv_tract = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state_tract").parentNode;

    const mapDiv_tract = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state_tract");


    insertAfter_Tract(sidebar_tract, mapDiv_tract)

    sidebar_tract.appendChild(selectList_tract);
    
  }

While this works in dataset_1_script.js, it does NOT work in the second chunk with dataset_2_script.js. In dataset_2_script.js the dropdown doesn't render in the DOM.  The issue is due to the fact that both scripts call the addElement function on document.body.onload. And, given that document.body.onload can only be called once, it makes sense that the dropdown element is successfully created in the first chunk (first script), but not in the second chunk (second script).
So my question is: is there a way to solve this issue in r2d3?  I do think I need body.onload to render the dropdown to the DOM.

One thing to note is that document.body.onload can only have one value.

@Pointy - yes, I'm a little unsure on how to call the createElement function two separate times using document.body.onload, since they are being called from physically two separate scripts.

You can add the event handlers with .addEventListener(), that allows as many handlers as you want.

@pointy thanks ! Can you elaborate how I’d implement that here in this example?

just pass your function to document.body.addEventListener(), details here

@Pointy I don't think i'm understanding still...I don't think the issue is adding an event listener like onclick or onchange - it's the fact that I need to add the dropdown element to the DOM, and document.body.onload is not letting me do that.  First and foremost I need to be able to add the dropdown element to the DOM.

As stated in the comments document.body.onload can only have one value. If you (or a third party vendor) try to assign a different handler to that event the previous one will be overwritten and not execute. Only the last assigned handler will execute. To see what handler is assigned to the onload event, simply paste document.body.onload  in the console.
Also as stated earlier if you would like to add multiple handlers to a load event then you will need add something like the following:
window.addEventListener('load', my_function)
Do not use document.addEventListener() as it is unreliable per this question.
